# RC522 has other pins than shown in all the tutorials

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, rfid, pins, nfc

I've bought an RFID RC522 module which I intend to use with my Raspberry Pi 3B+. I read the following tutorials and I noticed that their modules have other pins than the one I bought:

https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/02/rc522-rfid-tag-read-raspberry-pi

https://medium.com/coinmonks/for-beginners-how-to-set-up-a-raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522-reader-and-record-data-on-iota-865f67843a2d

https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/02/rc522-rfid-tag-read-raspberry-pi/

This is my RFID module:

[image]

It has the following pins (in case it's not readable in the photo):

**VCC RST GND MISO MOSI SCK NSS IRQ**

The modules used in the tutorials have the pins

**3.3V RST GND IRQ MISO MOSI SCK SDA**

Is the module just deprecated (2012)? Which pins of the module should I connect to which GPIO pins?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the PDF (portable document format) data sheet for the part you bought tell you?

Comment: @Andyaka On the label of the package it says 'QITA 13.56Mhz RFID Module Kits KeyCard ID Card CZ0225'. I do not have any other document. The seller wrote that it works with the Raspberry Pi and Arduino.

Comment: Therein lies the problem of buying stuff without the aforementioned data. Ask him because asking here will only get guesses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the correlation between your board and the ones from the tutorials is quite straightforward:

```
VCC  --> 3.3V
RST  --> RST
GND  --> GND
MISO --> MISO
MOSI --> MOSI
SCK  --> SCK
NSS  --> SDA
IRQ  --> IRQ
```

The only difference is that IRQ pin is at the end and not in the middle.

Comment: Can you add a bit of commentary around the renaming between NSS and SDA? Does that pin have multiple functions? Is there a configuration bit that needs to be set in order for the pin to operate in I2C mode?

Comment: @nanofarad the RC522 chip allows three types of interface: UART, SPI, I2C. But, the interface on this board is hardcoded with PCB design and it appears that this RFID module only supports SPI protocol

Comment: That would probably be good to edit into your post (since comments are ephemeral). If it only supports the SPI protocol, it would be good to mention that, and the particular function of the NSS pin in this version.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To decide which pins on the Pi to connect to your module you need to look at the software library you are using. It should indicate whether it uses SPI or I2C communications and which of the Raspberry Pi board's hardware devices are used.